# Can't dismiss mail composer using dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) and dismissViewControllerAnimated doesn't come up as an option

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I've imported MessageUI and created an extension to include MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate which includes dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) and this doesn't close the VC that pops up to send the message however this is the only option that comes up when typing dismiss.  I can't tell if that's what's required with the a newer Swift version as all other examples show dismissViewControllerAnimated.  Not sure what I'm missing?

**Action Button Code**

```
    @IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let toRecipient = ["\(Constants.SubmitFeedback.feedbackEmail)"]

    let mc = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mc.setToRecipients(toRecipient)
    mc.setSubject("Feedback for Gallery App")

    mc.setMessageBody("Name: \(String(describing: nameTextField.text!)) \nEmail: \(String(describing: emailTextField.text!)) \n\nMessage: \n\(String(describing: messageTextField.text!))", isHTML: false)

    self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**Extension with 'dismiss' command**

```
extension FeedViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("Failed")
    case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue:
        print("Saved")
    case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("Sent")
    default:
        break
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: I ended removing the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate as an extension and added it directly to the VC and I was able to change 'mc.mailComposeDelegate = self as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate' to 'mc.mailComposeDelegate = self' and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss)

> call this method on the presented view controller

i'm sure we all made the same mistake first time we used that api :-)

Comment: I tried adding the 'controller' prefix to the dismiss command and it didn't do anything.  Since the mail composer VC is a pop over I can swipe down but this isn't the UX I'd expect after either sending the email or cancelling out of the composer.  It should go away automatically.  Also Xcode made me change 'mc.mailComposeDelegate = self' to 'mc.mailComposeDelegate = self as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate' think that has anything to do with it?

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with the MFMailComposeViewController. If you look at the docs for the class you will see controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) in the sample code provided for that delegate callback. I suggest you read through the docs thoroughly and see if you did something wrong in your setup